# virt-install is looking for iso image, when I want to use a qcow2 image

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I'm absolutely new to stackoverflow, so I'm extremely sorry if my question has formatting issues.

I created a VM using virt-install:

```
virt-install \
--name guest \
--memory 2048 \
--vcpus 2 \ 
--disk size=8 \ 
--location /var/lib/libvirt/images/centos.iso \
--os-variant centos7.0 \
--check disk_size=off \
--graphics none \
--extra-args console=ttyS0
```

The above command works fine, but when I want to use a specific image which is a qcow2 image, Virt-install throws the error:

```
ERROR Command '['isoinfo', '-J', '-i', '/var/lib/libvirt/images/centos.qcow2', '-f']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Looks like virt-install is looking for an isofile since its running the isoinfo command to verify an iso image, eventhough I have a qcow2 image.

I might be able to pass a qcow2 using the `--disk` parameter instead of `--location`, but `--extra-args` only works with `--location`.

Kindly help me out, thank you in advance!

Comment: Try specifying the format: `--disk size=8,format=qcow2`

Comment: I'm hitting the same issue after specifying the format

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up two different concepts here. The `--location` flag is intended to provide the installation media, which will be an ISO image or a URL to a installable tree. The `--disk` flag would be to provide the storage to back the virtual disk of the VM being provisioned, which will typically be a qcow2 file or a raw file, or a block device.

I'm assuming the centos.iso image would be your installation media, and the centos.qcow2 image would be an  empty volume for the virtual disk into which you'll install the CentOS guest.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the confusion. I have an OS image which is a qcow2 format. I would like to use this as installation media. But using --location seems to call isoinfo to verify if it is a valid ISO, eventhough I provided the location of a qcow2 image. So I wanted to know if there was anyway to use a qcow2 image.

Comment: If it is a pre-built disk image, then there's no likely to be any installation process required. Instead you would do  'virt-install --import --file /var/lib/libvirt/images/your-prebuilt-disk.qcow2  ...other flags...'  to make it skip the install step entirely and just configure the disk image.